# Deploy Laravel 5.2 on Shared host error showing example.com/example.com

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, configuration, server

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/public/index.php?/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^/example.com/
```

Above is my `.htaccess` file which works fine on a Godaddy server. But on ShweHosting (shared host), it automatically redirects to `example.com/example.com` when using home (root route). i.e. When I want to go `example.com` it goes to `example.com/example.com` instead. Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Above error was solved. The problem is caused by default Cpanel redirect function and .htaccess. They don't overwrite for some kind of reason.